# [MIXED CHART.JS]animation option screws up chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

1. Open https://codepen.io/dhika345/pen/JxZJqp
2. Try to hover over the chart

You can see it's blinking every time when you hover over it which is caused by the animation option.

How to deal with it?

Code:

```
        var lineChartOptions = {
            animation: {
              easing: 'easeInOutBack'
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
                callbacks: {
                    title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        var arrDateTooltip = new Array();

                        tooltipItem.forEach(function (value, index) {
                            arrDateTooltip.push(hourTooltipCallbackLine[value.index])
                        })

                        return arrDateTooltip;
                    },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add code from your codepen into question text.

Answer (score 0):

You've done everything good, but there is one mistake. Check https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html

You can't declare color on way that you just set color to `0`. You can write `black` or use `'rgba(0,0,0)'`.

Comment: thank you. your answer sorts it out. now the tooltip screws up too. how to animate it only when it's initialized? any clue?

Comment: It'l animate only when is initialized, it's possible to animate again only when you update chart, so this what you are using is fine. What is happening with tooltip?

Comment: you can hover over the chart. you'll see it's (kind of) vibrating

Comment: Check this https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#position-modes, it act strange because you should use label callbeck no title.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "label callback no title". can you elaborate it?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YaLDY08 check this, you can add your date if you have `hourTooltipCallbackLine` as hash array, then call like  `return tooltipItem.xLabel + hourTooltipCallbackLine[tooltipItem.xLabel];`

Comment: it's still oscillating. I've updated the codepen. please, take a look

Comment: You can change 'animationDuration' change to `hover: {animationDuration: 0 }`

Comment: got it on `tooltips` and `datasets` object not working

Comment: exchange your current hover option to this what I wrote.

Comment: it solves it a bit but still not pleasing in the eyes when I hover the mouse rapidly

Comment: anyway you can fork it and play with it